# sort array with Number shuffle

Tags: ruby

i asked questions on the problem of Number shuffle https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/problems/154-permutations and received satisfied answers, but this exercise is not still completely clear for me. exercises asks to:

> Given a 3 or 4 digit number with distinct digits, return a sorted array of all the unique numbers that can be formed with those digits.
>
> **Example:**
>
> Given: `123`
>
> Return: `[123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321]`

there is a solution (See the Solution) below the exercise, that looks like this:

```
def number_shuffle(number)
  no_of_combinations = number.to_s.size == 3 ? 6 : 24
  digits = number.to_s.split(//)
  combinations = []
  combinations << digits.shuffle.join.to_i while combinations.uniq.size!=no_of_combinations
  combinations.uniq.sort
end
```

I have 2 questions, can anyone explain me:

1. `no_of_combinations` variable i explained so: if `number.to_s.size` equals 3 digits, then  number of combinations should be 6, otherwise 24. am i right or not?
2. what does it mean: `combinations.uniq.size!=no_of_combinations`. i know that operator `!=` designates 'not equals', but do not understand total sense.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. ... if `number.to_s.size` equals 3 digits, then number of combinations should be 6, otherwise 24. am i right or not?

Correct, because there are 6 ways to arrange 3 digits and 24 ways to arrange 4 digits.

> 2. what does it mean: `combinations.uniq.size!=no_of_combinations`.

The part before `while` is repeated until this equation is satisfied, i.e. a random combination is created:

```
digits = [1, 2 ,3]
digits.shuffle.join.to_i #=> 123
digits.shuffle.join.to_i #=> 132
digits.shuffle.join.to_i #=> 321
digits.shuffle.join.to_i #=> 123
```

... and this combination is added to the `combinations` array until the array contains `no_of_combinations` unique elements.

Of course, this is far from ideal, because the same combination(s) can be created over and over again.

Comment: "this is far from ideal, because the same combination(s) can be created over and over again." Most definitely, so it seems the solution given by the OP isn't a solution at all. Which makes a statement about the tutorial. :-/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line:

```
def number_shuffle(i)
   i.to_s.chars.permutation.map(&:join).map(&:to_i)
end
```

Output:

```
number_shuffle(123)
# => [123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321] 

number_shuffle(1234)
# => [1234, 1243, 1324, 1342, 1423, 1432, 2134, 2143, 2314, 2341, 2413, 2431, 3124, 3142, 3214, 3241, 3412, 3421, 4123, 4132, 4213, 4231, 4312, 4321]
```

The solution in the question is **wrong and inefficient**. It generates random permutations until finds the proper count of unique combinations. It's like solving an equation by substituting random values:

```
# x - 5 should be 0. Let's find x! 
x = rand() unless x - 5 == 0
```

**Don't do that.**

Comment: given the exercise and the name of the method, Ruby-Monk clearly doesn't want the best solution. But to show the learner how `Array#shuffle` is working. So in essence you are right, but this is irrelevant here IMO.

Comment: @astreal yep, you've given a very precise explanation of the function. I just intended to warn the author that the solution he provided is not relevant to the problem. `Shuffle` can be used in lottery games but not in combinatorics.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding the first question:**

Given that the number of permutation of the digits of a number WITH DISTINCT DIGITS is `n!` (`1 * 2 * ... * n`).

If the number has 3 digits then the number of permutation is `3! = 1 * 2 * 3 = 6`

If the number has 4 digits then the number of permutation is `4! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 = 24`

So in that particular case you are right. Be aware that this would not work if you had digits that repeats in that number.

**Regarding the second question:**

`combinations.uniq.size!=no_of_combinations` is a boolean test which returns `true` or `false`. Combined with the `while` statement: `some_code while boolean_test`, this means execute the code `some_code` while the `boolean_test` is true.

In your case:

```
combinations << digits.shuffle.join.to_i while
combinations.uniq.size!=no_of_combinations
```

means:

push `digits.shuffle.join.to_i` to the variable `combinations` (which is an array)
while `combinations.uniq.size!=no_of_combinations` is true, meaning while the size of the array (`combinations`) is less than the expected length (which is was computed before).

The algorithm here first determine the number of solution expected (6 or 24) then it picks a random shuffling of of the digits, add it to the solution if it does not exists and only stop when the number of solution is strictly equal to the number of solution expected.

This is clearly not the best solution (see @Oleg K. answer), however i guess the goal here was to show you how `Array#shuffle`is working.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**

You don't need to be told. Figure it out. Let `p(n)` be the number of ways you can arrange ("permute") the digits of a number having `n` distinct digits. First, suppose `n=1`. Then clearly,

```
p(1) = 1
```

Now suppose `n=2`. The first digit can precede or follow the second digit, so:

```
p(2) = 2*p(1) = 2
```

Now let `n` be any integer greater than `2`. For each arrangement of the last `n-1` digits, the first digit can be inserted in any of `n` positions. For example, suppose the number were `1234`. One arrangement of the last three digits is `423`. The first digit, `1` can be inserted in any of `4` locations: `1423, 4123, 4213, 4231`.

Therefore:

```
p(n) = n*p(n-1)
```

It appears that:

```
p(n) = n!
```

We can easily prove that's correct by induction:

```
p(1) = 1
p(2) = 2*1 = 2!
p(n) = n*p(n-1)
     = n*(n-1)!
     = n!
```

So:

```
p(3) = 3! = 6
p(4) = 4! = 4*3! = 4*6 = 24
```

Now that you know this formula, and know *why it is true*, you will not forget it.

**Q2**

Let's rewrite the method with some `puts` added:

```
def number_shuffle(number)
  no_of_combinations = number.to_s.size == 3 ? 6 : 24
  puts "no_of_combinations = #{no_of_combinations}"
  digits = number.to_s.split(//)
  puts "digits = #{digits}\n\n"
  combinations = []
  while true
    a = digits.shuffle.join.to_i 
    puts "digits.shuffle.join.to_i = #{a}"
    combinations << a
    puts "combinations = #{combinations}"
    b = combinations.uniq
    puts "  combinations.uniq = #{b}"
    c = b.size
    puts "  combinations.uniq.size = #{c}"
    puts "  combinations.uniq.size==no_of_combos = #{c==no_of_combinations}"
    break if c==no_of_combinations
  end
  combinations.uniq.sort
end
```

and try it:

```
number_shuffle(123)

no_of_combinations = 6
digits = ["1", "2", "3"]

digits.shuffle.join.to_i = 123
combinations = [123]
  combinations.uniq = [123]
  combinations.uniq.size = 1
  combinations.uniq.size==no_of_combinations = false

digits.shuffle.join.to_i = 321
combinations = [123, 321]
  combinations.uniq = [123, 321]
  combinations.uniq.size = 2
  combinations.uniq.size==no_of_combinations = false

digits.shuffle.join.to_i = 123
combinations = [123, 321, 123]
  combinations.uniq = [123, 321]
  combinations.uniq.size = 2
  combinations.uniq.size==no_of_combinations = false

digits.shuffle.join.to_i = 312
combinations = [123, 321, 123, 312]
  combinations.uniq = [123, 321, 312]
  combinations.uniq.size = 3
  combinations.uniq.size==no_of_combinations = false

digits.shuffle.join.to_i = 321
combinations = [123, 321, 123, 312, 321]
  combinations.uniq = [123, 321, 312]
  combinations.uniq.size = 3
  combinations.uniq.size==no_of_combinations = false
```

```
digits.shuffle.join.to_i = 132
combinations = [123, 321, 123, 312, 321, 132]
  combinations.uniq = [123, 321, 312, 132]
  combinations.uniq.size = 4
  combinations.uniq.size==no_of_combinations = false

digits.shuffle.join.to_i = 321
combinations = [123, 321, 123, 312, 321, 132, 321]
  combinations.uniq = [123, 321, 312, 132]
  combinations.uniq.size = 4
  combinations.uniq.size==no_of_combinations = false

digits.shuffle.join.to_i = 213
combinations = [123, 321, 123, 312, 321, 132, 321, 213]
  combinations.uniq = [123, 321, 312, 132, 213]
  combinations.uniq.size = 5
  combinations.uniq.size==no_of_combinations = false

digits.shuffle.join.to_i = 213
combinations = [123, 321, 123, 312, 321, 132, 321, 213, 213]
  combinations.uniq = [123, 321, 312, 132, 213]
  combinations.uniq.size = 5
  combinations.uniq.size==no_of_combinations = false

digits.shuffle.join.to_i = 123
combinations = [123, 321, 123, 312, 321, 132, 321, 213, 213, 123]
  combinations.uniq = [123, 321, 312, 132, 213]
  combinations.uniq.size = 5
  combinations.uniq.size==no_of_combinations = false

digits.shuffle.join.to_i = 231
combinations = [123, 321, 123, 312, 321, 132, 321, 213, 213, 123, 231]
  combinations.uniq = [123, 321, 312, 132, 213, 231]
  combinations.uniq.size = 6
  combinations.uniq.size==no_of_combinations = true

#=> [123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321]
```